# ATS. How to compile non void function?

Tags: ats

I'm a newbie in ML languages. I'm reading the ATS manual and I in mad now.
I read half of manual and there is no explanation in it how to compile a non-void function.

Only one example with `"hello world"` program.

```
ats
val x = "hello"

implement main0 () = print x
```

But if I change `x` to `2 * 2` it will raise an error.

Should I read the manual without capability to compile code and test it? Disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following line for
some library functions:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
```

ATS may not be a good language for beginners as it assumes
a fair amount of knowledge of ML and C.